# Touch Flash action script 3

Tags: actionscript-3

Porque acontece isso?

Criei um circulo converto ele em BOTÃO, e dou a ele qualquer ação,  se eu deixar um dos meus dedos pressionado na tela fora do circulo, e toca-lo com meu outro dedo ele não executa qualquer tipo de ação.

Answer (score 0):

Para eventos de toque, você deve definir qual o [tipo de toque](http://help.adobe.com/pt_BR/as3/dev/WSb2ba3b1aad8a27b0-6ffb37601221e58cc29-8000.html) que o seu aplicativo irá receber. O ActionScript disponibiliza três tipos:

1. `GESTURE` Você realiza um movimento e ele toma uma ação)
2. `NONE` O touch é tratado como click do mouse
3. `TOUCH_POINT` Cada toque que você dá na tela é gerado um "touchID" para manipulação.

*([ref](http://help.adobe.com/pt_BR/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/ui/MultitouchInputMode.html).)*

O padrão é GESTURE, portanto, para definir mais de um toque na tela, você deve usar:

```
Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT;
```

E então, para tratar os eventos:

```
botao.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN, comecouTocar); //Início
botao.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_END, terminouTouch); //Término
botao.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_MOVE, moveTouch); //Movimento
botao.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_TAP, toqueTouch); //Toque (Equivalente ao MOUSE_CLICK)
.............
```

Para ler os IDs dos toques que são efetuados pelo usuário, você deve ler a propriedade `touchPointID` do objeto `TouchEvent`, assim:

```
function toqueTouch(e:TouchEvent):void {
    trace(e.touchPointID); //ID do toque do usuário
}
```

[Neste link](http://help.adobe.com/pt_BR/as3/dev/WS1ca064e08d7aa93023c59dfc1257b16a3d6-7ffe.html) há todas as referências para tratar toques na tela. Caso você não consiga, verifique se o dispositivo que você está testando sua aplicação suporta multitoques, alguns leem apenas um, [este site](http://scripty2.com/demos/touch/touchspector/) pode ajudar.